# Writing multi line string to CSV file

Tags: csv, go

How can I write a multi line value to a CSV file using the `encoding/csv` package?

```
fh, err := os.Create(fileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not create file: %v", err)
}
defer fh.Close()
w := csv.NewWriter(fh)

normalValue := "I am a single line value"
multiValue := []string{"I am a ", "multi line value"}

w.Write([]string{normalValue, multiValue})
```

The result I would expect in the resulting CSV file:

```
I am a single line value,"I am a 
multi line value"
```

How can I realize this, since `csv.Write` does not accept `[]string` as an argument? Simply appending `\n` between each element of the multi line value does not achieve anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the `\n` in your multiline value. You can do this, for example, by using [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join):

```
w.Write([]string{
    normalValue,
    strings.Join(multiValue, "\n"),
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uWJnClpQ1OT

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same thing earlier. But then I processed the value further before writing it out, removing the newline character again -.-